# xmpp - send/receive file using turnsocket in ios

Tags: ios, xmppframework

I'm working on chat app. Now I want to send a file using TurnSocket class but socket failed to connect.

```
- (void)sendToOtherDevice:(NSData *)fileData receiverJid:(NSString *)receiverJid {

    XMPPJID *JID = [XMPPJID jidWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",receiverJid,resourceID]];

    NSLog(@"%@",[JID full]);

    NSLog(@"Attempting TURN connection to %@", JID);

    [TURNSocket setProxyCandidates:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:JID.domain, nil]];
    TURNSocket *turnSocket = [[TURNSocket alloc] initWithStream:[self xmppStream] toJID:JID];
    [turnSockets addObject:turnSocket];
    [turnSocket startWithDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
}
```

**TurnSocket Delegate Method**

```
- (void)turnSocket:(TURNSocket *)sender didSucceed:(GCDAsyncSocket *)socket {

    NSLog(@"TURN Connection succeeded!");
    NSLog(@"You now have a socket that you can use to send/receive data to/from the other person.");

    [turnSockets removeObject:sender];
}

- (void)turnSocketDidFail:(TURNSocket *)sender {

    NSLog(@"TURN Connection failed!");
    [turnSockets removeObject:sender];

}
```

**Log:**

SEND:

```
<iq type="get" to="meinantrieb.net" id="C6CF8EEE-B74E-45C8-8881-89BD0835056E">
<query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items"/></iq>
```

RECV:

```
<iq xmlns="jabber:client" from="meinantrieb.net" to="kirit@meinantrieb.net/267698820914007696033596" id="C6CF8EEE-B74E-45C8-8881-89BD0835056E" type="result">
<query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items">
<item jid="conference.meinantrieb.net"/>
<item jid="irc.meinantrieb.net"/>
<item jid="proxy.meinantrieb.net"/>
<item jid="pubsub.meinantrieb.net"/>
<item jid="vjud.meinantrieb.net"/></query></iq>
```

SEND:

```
<iq type="get" to="proxy.meinantrieb.net" id="22D98197-F1F2-4D8F-AA9C-E1076D0EF9F7">
<query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info"/></iq>
```

RECV:

```
<iq xmlns="jabber:client" from="proxy.meinantrieb.net" to="kirit@meinantrieb.net/267698820914007696033596" id="22D98197-F1F2-4D8F-AA9C-E1076D0EF9F7" type="result">
<query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info">
<identity category="proxy" type="bytestreams" name="SOCKS5 Bytestreams"/>
<feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info"/>
<feature var="vcard-temp"/>
<feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams"/>
<x xmlns="jabber:x:data" type="result">
<field var="FORM_TYPE" type="hidden">
<value>http://jabber.org/network/serverinfo</value></field></x></query></iq>
```

SEND:

```
<iq type="get" to="proxy.meinantrieb.net" id="84AFA217-7F71-48B4-B56C-66995FE20490">
<query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams"/></iq>
```

RECV:

```
<iq xmlns="jabber:client" from="proxy.meinantrieb.net" to="kirit@meinantrieb.net/267698820914007696033596" id="84AFA217-7F71-48B4-B56C-66995FE20490" type="result">
<query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams">
<streamhost jid="proxy.meinantrieb.net" host="0.0.0.0" port="7777"/></query></iq>
```

SEND:

```
<iq type="set" to="vote@meinantrieb.net/(null)" id="694B5F07-3A70-4556-9268-1D47AC251229">
<si xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/si" id="694B5F07-3A70-4556-9268-1D47AC251229" profile="http://jabber.org/protocol/si/profile/file-transfer">
<file xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/si/profile/file-transfer" name="abc.txt" size="2239350"/>
<feature xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/feature-neg">
<x xmlns="jabber:x:data" type="form">
<field var="stream-method" type="list-single"><option><value>http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams</value></option><option><value>http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb</value></option></field></x></feature></si></iq>
```

RECV:

```
<iq xmlns="jabber:client" from="vote@meinantrieb.net/(null)" to="kirit@meinantrieb.net/267698820914007696033596" type="result" id="694B5F07-3A70-4556-9268-1D47AC251229">
<si xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/si">
<feature xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/feature-neg">
<x xmlns="jabber:x:data" type="submit">
<field var="stream-method"><value>http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams</value></field></x></feature></si></iq>
```

SEND:

```
<iq type="set" to="vote@meinantrieb.net/(null)" id="694B5F07-3A70-4556-9268-1D47AC251229"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams" sid="694B5F07-3A70-4556-9268-1D47AC251229" mode="tcp">
<streamhost xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams" jid="proxy.meinantrieb.net" host="0.0.0.0" port="7777"/></query></iq>
```

RECV:

```
<iq xmlns="jabber:client" from="vote@meinantrieb.net/(null)" to="kirit@meinantrieb.net/267698820914007696033596" type="error" id="694B5F07-3A70-4556-9268-1D47AC251229">
<error code="404" type="cancel">
<item-not-found xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/></error></iq>
```

**TURN Connection failed!**

Any help or suggestion will be well appreciated.

Comment: is socks proxy responding on 7777 port?

Comment: and what xmpp server are you using? maybe you have to activate some module on its side to act as a socks proxy, for instance on ejabberd: http://www.ejabberd.im/node/9033

Comment: @VincentG How can I test the proxy server on ejabberd.

Comment: simply try something like telnet localhost 7777 to see if if connects or lsof/netstat to look for open ports

Comment: I try and It connected to localhost successfully.

Comment: and does `proxy.meinantrieb.net` resolve to your machine? try connecting to this host and not localhost. If that doesnt work, you should try investigate in ejabberd source/logs...

Comment: That could help, here is the ejabberd part sending that 404: https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/blob/master/src/mod_proxy65_service.erl#L193

Answer (score 2):

it's better to focus on getting two jabber clients talking first as there are many issues in communicating to other clients as far as i know. (i.e. Adium, Spark)
 To establish a connection between two jabber clients is now working. There are indeed some issues to connect to other jabber clients like Adium or Spark.

For two jabber clients to connect, one has to be the server (target) and one has to be the client (requester).

Therefore, we need to implement the incoming request from another client. To achieve this, we need fews lines of code for incoming TURN request.

```
- (BOOL)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveIQ:(XMPPIQ *)iq
{
    DDLogVerbose(@"%@: %@ - %@", THIS_FILE, THIS_METHOD, [iq elementID]);

    if ([TURNSocket isNewStartTURNRequest:iq]) {
        NSLog(@"IS NEW TURN request..");
        TURNSocket *turnSocket = [[TURNSocket alloc] initWithStream:[self xmppStream] incomingTURNRequest:iq];
        [turnSockets addObject:turnSocket];
        [turnSocket startWithDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
        [turnSocket release];
    }

    return YES;
}
```

if you test on two jabber clients, you'd be able to establish a connection from either side.  Receiving data from Spark is fine though sending data still got the 406 error. 
Cant communicate with Adium in either way.
My suggestion:

1. Try a dedicated server on your own. (I am using the VPS hosting by Linode)
2. Obtain your jid from primaryResource.jid

Comment: Yes.I also add code for incoming request. When I send the file from one client to another than `if([TURNSocket isNewStartTURNRequest:iq])`  is true for both clients.

Answer (score 0):

Please be sure you are using correct to and from jid while sending iq using turnsocket over xmppStream.

like this.
to: arpan@fb.purologics.com/hsdvydvdv
from : push@fb.purologics.com/ksjbdjdd
after '/' "hsdvydvdv" and "ksjbdjdd" is resource id.Its mandatory while sending iq to make proper connection.

you can get full jid of to and from in following method of AppDelegate :

```
- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceivePresence:(XMPPPresence *)presence
{
    DDLogVerbose(@"%@: %@ - %@", THIS_FILE, THIS_METHOD, [presence fromStr]);

  //  NSString *presenceType = [presence type]; // online/offline
    NSString *myUsername = [[sender myJID] user];
    NSString *presenceFromUser = [[presence from] user];

    NSLog(@" Printing full jid of user %@",[[sender myJID] full]);
    NSLog(@"Printing full jid of user %@",[[sender myJID] resource]);
    NSLog(@"From user %@",[[presence from] full]);
    senderFullID=[[presence from] full];



}
```